# Filter data in observable

Tags: javascript, angular

I received an object of the object and I required 4 properties from each object and I cannot make any changes from the backend.

Currently, I am filtering like this:

```
fetchData(data) {
  return this.http
    .get(this._apiConfiguration.apiConfig.releasetable + '/' + data)
    .pipe(
      map(responseData => {
        console.log(typeof responseData); // object
        let posts = [];
        for (const key in responseData) {
          posts.push({
            Name: responseData[key].name,
            ID: responseData[key].id,
            project_ID: responseData[key].project_id,
            date: responseData[key].date
          });
        }

        return posts;
      }),
      catchError(errorRes => {
        return throwError(errorRes);
      })
    );
}
```

Note that each object has 30 properties. Is there any better way to filter?

Comment: It would be nive if you have showed the structure of your data structures.

Comment: It's very hard to give you any suggestion without your structures. However I guess you can use map again inside the map to avoid the for loop.